# How to 'multiply' FFTs

Tags: fft

In certain algorithms its required to 'multiply' FFTs.  How does one actually do that when you have real/imaginary pair data?

Say I have twos FFTs a and b, should I for each bin just multiply a[k].real * b[k].real and a[k].imag * b[k].imag ?

Comment: that's not how you multiply complex numbers!

Answer (score 1):

> How does one actually do that when you have real/imaginary pair data?

You do a complex multiply: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexMultiplication.html

Please note that "multiplying FFTs" implements circular convolution, not linear convolution. Hence frequency domain filtering typically uses overlap-add or similar algorithms. These are indeed based on multiplying spectra but there is extra "stuff" that needs to get done to get the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

About half of practical signal processing work is understanding how the real world impacts your signals and visa-versa (i.e., how radios work, or how the human hearing system works, etc.).  The other half is understanding the underlying math.

Most introductory courses to signal processing either expect you to come in the door understanding complex arithmetic, or teach you how in the first week or so.  If you don't know how to multiply complex numbers together, you you haven't gotten that basic instruction.

You need to dig into the basics.  Find a book on signal processing and start self-studying, or find a class on Khan Academy or MIT or some other place that publishes courses on YouTube and start doing guided study, or enroll in some university classes.

1. Don't expect it to be easy
2. Do expect it to make signal processing work easier and far more clear